# Form file upload not working with zip

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <label for="file_upload" id="btn">Click to select file</label>
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="ADD">
</form>


if(isset($_POST["upload"])){
    $path = $_FILES['file_upload']['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo $ext;
    echo "test";
}
```

Can someone tell me why the echo only get swinged out if i don't include a file in my upload? If i just click submit without selecting a file, it works. If i select a file and submit it does nothing. No errors and no echo. File_uploads is on in php.ini and i use MAMP if that should have anything to do with it

Edit:
Well, i found out that this only occurs when i try to upload a zip file. Anyone know?

Comment: Nothing as in a blank page? Check your server's error logs.

Comment: Is the **if** statement inside php tags or... ? Shouldn't you be looking for `$_POST["file_upload"]` ?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Just a blank page.
The php code is of course in php tags, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Obeously it was that the max filesize which by default is 2M. I changed that by adding

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```

to htaccess if anyone should encounter the same problem